# How to install/remove Java quick start service from command line

Tags: java, windows, scripting

Would like to know how to install/remove Java quick start service from command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
net stop JavaQuickStarterService
```

I'm not sure why you tagged this "vb" and "scripting". If you need a vbs solution, scroll to the bottom of [this page](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Systems_Management_Server/Q_25271143.html)